# Unable to install composer in xampp php 7.3.9 in windows 10

Tags: composer-php

Iam unable to install composer in my windows system with Xampp installed with PHP version 7.3.9

Please find the error message.

"A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist."

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which lines of that error message are unclear to you?

Comment: I have removed the comment for openssl in php.ini
Checked the extension_dir value. Tried with below mentioned values one by one
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
extension_dir="/ext"

Comment: I have removed the comment for openssl in php.ini
Checked the extension_dir value. Tried with below mentioned values one by one
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
Checked the extension path and vrified the warnings as well.

Comment: Reproduced the issue and Please see the inline comments. The composer was already installed in program files.

Answer (score 0):

Please See the Inline comments for errors and Warnings

1A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Answer: Checked the extension_dir(extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"). Path was correct So I checked for the below warnings.

Program Output: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.),

Answer: Commented ;extension=php_pdo.dll

C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning: Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.),

Answer: Removed these extensions which I have used for connecting to the SQL server

C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP

Answer: Removed these extensions which I have used for connecting to the SQL server

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Answer: Openssl was loaded twice, Comment one in php.ini file

Also please check that the composer is already installed in your program files

Thanks

Vysakh